# Dataflow needs bigquery.datasets.get permission for the underlying table in authorized view

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In a dataflow pipeline, I'm reading from a BigQuery Authorized View:

> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query = "SELECT col1 FROM proj2.dataset2.auth_view1", use_standard_sql=True))

This is the error which I'm getting:

> Error:
>    Message: Access Denied: Dataset proj1:dataset1: The user xxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.datasets.get permission for dataset proj1:dataset1.

proj1:dataset1 has the base table for the view auth_view1.

According to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/557) issue in DataflowJavaSDK, dataflow seems to be directly executing some metadata query against the underlying table.

Is there a fix available for this issue in Apache Beam SDK?

Comment: I use apache-beam 2.8.0

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly setting the Query location is also a solution in the Apache Beam Java SDK, using the `withQueryLocation` option of [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.TypedRead.html#withQueryLocation-java.lang.String-).

It looks like setting the query location is not possible in the [Python SDK](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySource) yet.

Comment: does `withQueryLocation` resolve this issue? Why is that?

Comment: Hello Pablo, according to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/557#issuecomment-417044474) the `withQueryLocation` option would avoid the metadata read. Unfortunately, last time I checked, this option was not available for the Python SDK.